# Cannot connect to GIT from jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have run Jenkins on AIX with:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8082
```

In the Jenkins job configure > Source Code Management > Git, I enter

```
Repository URL: user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/opt/git/project.git
```

where XXX is the ip of the server.

I got the following error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/opt/git/project.git HEAD" returned status code 255:
stdout: 
stderr: exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /usr/bin/git because of the following errors:
0509-150   Dependent module /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not be loaded.
0509-152   Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive
```

I have tested on both AIX and WinXP. It works fine on the windows machine. But I need the Jenkins to be on the AIX server. Have googled the error but in vain. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have libiconv installed (either in /usr/... or in /opt), as in [this thread](http://thr3ads.net/samba/2006/10/1784274-Re-Samba-3.0.23c-and-libiconv-on-AIX-5.3) or [this one](http://thr3ads.net/samba/2005/01/1756482-libiconv.so.2-is-not-found).

```
find /opt -name "libiconv*" -print
find /usr -name "libiconv*" -print
```

Try and unset `$LIBPATH`.

Type `ldd /usr/bin/git` to check where git looks for its dependencies.

---

The [OP Lai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345845/lai) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539765/cannot-connect-to-git-from-jenkins/16540964?noredirect=1#comment23784504_16540964) having used one of the solutions:

> When I use `ldd /usr/bin/git`, it gives `/opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)`.
>   But the Git error is from `/usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)`.
>
> There is a `libiconv.la` in `/opt/freeware/lib` but not in `/usr/lib`.
>   I copied it to /usr/lib then it works.

Comment: When I use `ldd /usr/bin/git`, it gives `/opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)`. But the Git error is from `/usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)`. I am confused. I got libiconv.a from both locations.

Comment: There is a `libiconv.la` in `/opt/freeware/lib` but not in `/usr/lib`. I copied it to `/usr/lib` then it is done~

Comment: @Lai sounds good. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this even though I have no `LIBPATH` configured in shell, but processes forked from java had. Consequently, git did not worked when invoked from java but worked just fine otherwise.

IBM JDK uses `LIBPATH` to manage own shared libraries but as any environment variable it is inherited by subprocesses where it can cause problems that are not present when `LIBPATH` is not set at all.

As IBM JDK prepends existing `LIBPATH` and not replacing it, it should be enough to set `LIBPATH` for the java process with all the paths necessary for the forked processes so it will be inherited.

Comment: LIBPATH isn't a solution - it should never be used in production.  The JDK doesn't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux or Solaris, and why not?  I think the reason LIBPATH is set on AIX is that developers don't understand AIX as well as they do Linux/Solaris.